# Is a good idea use Couchbase with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cordova, couchbase

I'm going to start a new web project in Rails (surely with a phonegap app too) and I wondered if it's a good idea to use Couchbase with Rails.

I think that one of the best things that rails have, is activerecord. Changing this behavior, I believe, is not use the power of Rails... but maybe I am wrong.

I have find a [gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/couchbase) for ruby and a "ugly" [tutorial](http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-sdk-ruby-1.0/tutorial.html).

has somebody used this combination? Is better to use other technology instead Rails with Couchbase?

Thanks for your opinions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it's perfectly acceptable to use rails and Couchbase together.  Here are some links that will help get you started!

Official documentation of Rails and Couchbase together http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-sdk-ruby-1.3/#couchbase-and-rails-tutorial

In place of active record I'd suggest going with the couchbase ruby model.  You can find it on github here.  https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-ruby-model  Basically it is like active record but aimed at Couchbase, the github page readme covers the functionality well.

If you haven't yet installed the ruby Couchbase sdk I'd follow this http://www.couchbase.com/communities/ruby/getting-started  Remember to install the libcouchbase C library first, it is step 1.0 but a lot of people seem to miss it! :)

EDIT - Here is a blog post I found specifically covering Couchbase and Rails using the Couchbase model  http://blog.couchbase.com/ruby-rails-and-couchbase-model-social-application

I have an example sinatra app, I know it's not rails but it is Ruby and is similar to how you'd work with Couchbase.  You can find it here https://github.com/scalabilitysolved/couchbase_sinatra_demo

Good luck!